# Are there any uncharted POIs on the planets you're exploring?

Tags: mass-effect

When exploring a planet with Mako, there are usually three points of interest each of these types:

1. Fallen spacecraft, contains story object. Sometimes these are Prothean objects
2. Minerals that can me marked for future mining by the Alliance (pressumably). For some reason, this requires "hacking" them.
3. A quest mission, typically a structure that can be entered so you can kill everyone inside.

All of those typically appear on map. Are there any objects that are *not* highlighted on the map? Or are any of the POI types mentioned above sometimes hidden from the map, requiring manual survey of the terrain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some POIs that do not appear on the global survey map (the full screen map). However, they will show in the mini-map in your display as you are driving around and get near them.

There are no POIs that are completely marker-less and required manual terrain survey—as in walking around hoping that a use prompt comes up. They will always at least show on the mini-map when you get close enough for them to be within the mini-map range. In other words, they will always show in the mini-map.

Primarily these are optional resources that are credits or just more resources. Sometimes the "military tags", "research", etc. that are for completing achievements. None are required or are super special really.